# How to run code in JavaScript, only when a variable is defined?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple function in JavaScript:

```
function waitThenRun(objectToWaitFor, callback) {
   // logic to periodically check for objectToWaitFor to become something
   // then call the callback
}
```

And I intend to use it as:

```
waitThenRun(someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater, function() {
    // Doing something with someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater
});
```

Yet I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater is not
>   defined

How do you handle this?

In simpler terms, I want to run a piece of code only when a global JSON variable is defined, and I can't determine when and where it gets defined. Sometimes it gets defined after my code, sometimes before my code, sometimes a second later, sometimes 5 seconds later. It's non-deterministic.

Comment: What do you mean you `and I can't determine when it gets defined`? Isn't it defined somewhere in your code?

Comment: I mean my code might run before its definition, or after its definition. It's non-deterministic.

Comment: Variables are passed by value, not by reference. There's no way for a function to test whether the variable is defined in the caller's scope.

Comment: @Barmar, then how do you make sure it's defined? It's somehow similar to jQuery's `$(document).ready()`, but for global JSON object.

Comment: You are fighting against the way things are done in javascript. Usually one would use a callback or an event listener to know when something has happened. You have code that is defining the variable — you should call your function or a callback there (this is how  `$(document).ready()` works -- it takes a callback). Everything else with timers and polling will be a hack.

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch an event on the `window` when you define your JSON Object and add an event listener for that event on the window. This way, you will not need to use a `setInterval` to continuously check if a global variable is defined.

```js
function defineJSON(){
  window.JSONObj = {x: "something"};
  triggerEvent("JSONDefined", window, {JSONObjName: "JSONObj"});//fire a custom event on the window when you define the JSON Object
}
function triggerEvent(type, obj, data){
  var ev;
  if (document.createEvent) {
    ev = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    ev.initEvent(type, true, true);
  } else {
    ev = document.createEventObject();
    ev.eventType = type;
  }
  ev.eventName = type;
  if(data){
   for(var key in data){
     if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        ev[key] = data[key];
     }
   }
  }
  if (document.createEvent) {
    obj.dispatchEvent(ev);
  } else {
    obj.fireEvent("on" + ev.eventType, ev);//for < IE8
  }
}
window.addEventListener("JSONDefined", function(ev){
  //this event handler will be called when the JSON Object is defined
  console.log("JSON defined:", window[ev.JSONObjName]);
});
setTimeout(function(){
   defineJSON();
}, 2000);//define JSON Object after 2 seconds (just for this example)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a global variable, you can pass the variable name as a string. Since global variables become properties of the `window` object, the function can then check whether `window[objectToWaitFor]` is defined.

```
function waitThenRun(objectToWaitFor, callback) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (window[objectToWaitFor] !== undefined) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
        }
    }            
}

waitThenRun("someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater", function() {
    // do something with someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using

```
   var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if (JsonObject) {
//execute your method here
      console.log("Exists!");
      clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
}, 100); // check every 100ms
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? That `if (JsonObject)` is exactly where I get error. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

All global variables are attached to the `window` object so can pass the variable name to your function as a string and check if it exists on the `window` and then run your callback if it does. Snippet:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater = {hello: 'world'};
}, 1000);

function waitThenRun(globalObj, callback) {
  let intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (window[globalObj] !== undefined) {
      callback(window[globalObj]);
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 200);
}

waitThenRun('someObjectThatWillBeDefinedLater', console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use metaprogramming like JS proxies to intercept  the set method of an objects property. Something like this:

```
function tracePropAccess(obj, propKeys) {
    const propKeySet = new Set(propKeys);
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            if (propKeySet.has(propKey)) {
                console.log('GET '+propKey);
            }
            return Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
        },
        set(target, propKey, value, receiver) {
            if (propKeySet.has(propKey)) {
                console.log('SET '+propKey+'='+value);
            }
            return Reflect.set(target, propKey, value, receiver);
        },
    });
}
```

the snippet was taken from [here](http://2ality.com/2015/10/intercepting-method-calls.html)

In your example, when the set property gets called you can check if the value meets your expected value and do as you wish with it.